# java.lang.RuntimeException:Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null,request=1,result=-1,data=Intent{dat=file:///storage/0EE6-4002/Mete/test.jpg}}

Tags: android, file, android-fileprovider

I'm getting picture via app from storage. Normally, uri that comes from data in onActivityResult is not null and starting with "content://" for picture. But some apps gives me uri starting with "file://" for same picture. Glide also wont work with "file://" uri. So i wanna get uri from FileProvider. When im give this uri to FileProvider, i gets this error;

```
2021-01-10 19:01:55.453 30049-30049/com.example.photoselector E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.photoselector, PID: 30049
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/0EE6-4002/Mete/IMG_20210108_120951.jpg typ=image/jpeg flg=0x3 }} 
to activity {com.example.photoselector/com.example.photoselector.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/0EE6-4002/Mete/IMG_20210108_120951.jpg
```

There is no problem when the same picture uri comes with the "content://", when it comes with the "file://" from another app, I get an error.

Im create Intent via this code:

```
private fun initData() {
        button_storage.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.type = "image/*"
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
            startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(
                    intent,
                    "Select App"
                ), SELECT_PICTURE
            )
        }
    }
```

gettin Uri from :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        when (resultCode) {
            Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                isExistCheck.isChecked = false

                setImageWiaUri(data?.data ?: tempFileUri)//tempFileUri for camera option

                when (requestCode) {
                    CAMERA_PICTURE -> {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "CAMERA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    SELECT_PICTURE -> {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "STORAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                }
            }
            Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "CANCELED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my code:

```
private fun setImageWiaUri(uri: Uri) {
        isExistCheck.isChecked = isFileExist(uri)
        var imgUri = uri

        if (isFileExist(uri)) {
            if (uri.toString().split(":")[0] == "file") {

               imgUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    "com.example.photoselector.fileprovider",
                    File(uri.toString())
                )
            }

            Glide.with(this)
                .load(imgUri)
                .into(image)

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "File does not exist...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

my provider_paths :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache_files"
        path="."/>
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
    <external-media-path
        name="external_media"
        path="." />
    <external-path
        name="externals"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache_files"
        path="." />

</paths>
```

How can i solve this, or how can i convert "file://" uri to "content://" uri?

Answer (score 1):

> But some apps gives me uri starting with "file://". Glide also wont work with "file://" uri

It is the job of an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` implementation to return to you a `Uri` that is useful. You might be able to eliminate some of the troublesome apps by adding `CATEGORY_OPENABLE` to your `Intent`, indicating that you want to be able to open the content identified by the `Uri`.

Glide can work with a `file://` `Uri`, if your app has permission to access that file.

> how can i convert "file://" uri to "content://" uri?

That is not your problem. `content://` is not a magic string that means "the `Uri` will work", and `file://` is not a magic string that means "the `Uri` will not work".

You did not explain the specific problem you encountered with Glide. My guess is that you do not have read access to the file. If so, `FileProvider` does not give you read access by magic, any more than a `HeyThisClassIsMagic` class will give you read access. Either your app has read access, or it does not.

Make sure that your app holds the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and requests it at runtime. Also, ensure that your app has `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the `<application>` element in the manifest. These steps will increase the likelihood that you will be able to read the content identified by the `Uri`.

If that does not help, then I suggest that you ask a separate question, where you show how you are using the returned `file://` `Uri` with Glide and what specific error you get.